# What does margin: auto do?

Tags: html, css, frontend

So I have a navigation bar menu in my html which has a hover effect to the links.
When I am setting the margin property to auto, the hover effect moves from the center to the edges of the links.

```
.nav-links ul li::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #f44336;
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, when I am settings margin value to any other value, e.g, 5px, the hover effect moves from left to right. What is the reason behind this ?

I am just beginner in front-end development, so I don't have much knowledge of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Block-level elements *have* to take exactly 100% of the width of their containing block. When the width is 0%, 100% of that containing block space is "spare".

`margin:auto` on block-level element takes up that "spare" horizontal space. If it's set on both sides, the spare space is shared equally between the two sides.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #f44336;
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-links">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Pictures of Kittens</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As the transition of the width moves from 0% to 100%, the space space reduces and the margins get equally smaller on both sides, expanding the bar from the middle.

When the margins have a value, the li elements are said to be "over-constrained", and the spare space has to be dealt with differently. If the layout direction is left-to-right (as is normally the case) the margin-right value is ignored and is whatever value is necessary to fill the space is used instead.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #f44336;
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-links">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Pictures of Kittens</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

So the left margin stays the same 5px, and the right margin is set initially to `100% - (5px + 0%)` and as the transition happens it reduces the right margin gradually to -5px (i.e. `100% - (5px + 100%)`) and the bar grows from left to right.

You can also see that if we set the container's direction to rtl, it's the right margin that stays fixed and the left margin that reduces, so that the bar grows from right to left.

```css
li {
    direction: rtl;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #f44336;
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-links">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Pictures of Kittens</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this was so detailed. It helped me and I also googled it. So thanks

Answer (score 0):

The margin property in CSS is the outermost ring of how much room an element takes up (Diagram below). Increasing the number will give it more empty space on all 4 sides.

[image: Margin, border, padding, element content diagram]

---

When you set the property to `auto` it will set the margin on the top and bottom to 0 and center the content on the horizontal axis.